# Helm template does not contain information about serviceMonitor

Tags: kubernetes-helm, ingress-nginx, servicemonitor

I am trying to deploy ingress controller with service monitor, i am using helm values file which looks like that:

```
controller:
  replicaCount: 3
  minAvailable: 1

  config:
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"
    use-proxy-protocol: "true"
    keep-alive: "3600"
  service:
    externalTrafficPolicy: Local
    type: LoadBalancer
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: true

rbac:
  create: true

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
```

when i run helm template with my values file provided, service monitor is not visible.

```
helm template ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --values values.yaml --version "4.0.5"
```

Does anyone had similar problem?
Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceMonitor has 3 conditions to be populated, make sure that your cluster and configs meet these conditions: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/6299c39842c31ff1e17d72503003ca36e2976a9a/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-servicemonitor.yaml#L1

your cluster should support: monitoring.coreos.com/v1 API version

if you use an older chart version where the API condition is not there, you will be able to deploy the ServiceMonitor with your current values.yaml

```
helm template ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --values values.yaml --version "3.15.2" | grep -i mon
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-servicemonitor.yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
```

Also, note that: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/

```
Render chart templates locally and display the output.

Any values that would normally be looked up or retrieved in-cluster will be faked locally. Additionally, none of the server-side testing of chart validity (e.g. whether an API is supported) is done.
```

This means if you run the command line on your machine, it will never show the `ServiceMonitor` unless you have a local k8s cluster that supports `monitoring.coreos.com/v1` or you fake it too :) as below

```
helm template ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --values values.yaml --version "4.0.5" --api-versions "monitoring.coreos.com/v1" | grep -i mon
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-servicemonitor.yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
```

Comment: The problem was connected with not valid helm chart version, thank you for your comment :)

Comment: what do you mean by `not valid helm chart version`, you were using 4.0.5 which is a valid version and it is available